# Load a webpage in another webpage with jQuery using .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a way to load a webpage in another webpage using [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in jQuery.

The instructions listed on the page weren't very clear.

Let's say the domain is "example.com" and the page I'm trying to load is located at "example.com/page".

Answer (score 2):

API explains enough: http://api.jquery.com/load/
`$('#result').load('/page');`

Where `#result` is the div with id result. Inside that div, the page `/page` will be loaded.

Comment: Yup. ZeroG, take special note of the documentation; trying to load a complete working HTML page (with head, script, body, etc.) into something like a div will probably not work, but you have the option to load a partial.